# Remove space between widgets in row flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to remove the space between two or more Text widgets in a Row.

This is the code using a Row

```
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        //   textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
        //   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
        children: [
          Text(
            r'$ ' + formatNumber(valueText),
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xff210049),
              fontSize: smallTextSize,
              fontFamily: 'RedHat',
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            ',00',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xff210049),
              fontSize: smallTextSize,
              fontFamily: 'RedHat',
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

I also tried using a RichText, but the result is the same:

```
          RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
          text: r'$ ' + formatNumber(valueText),
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Color(0xff210049),
            fontSize: smallTextSize,
            fontFamily: 'RedHat',
          ),
          children: <TextSpan>[
            TextSpan(
              text: ',00',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Color(0xff210049),
                fontSize: smallTextSize,
                fontFamily: 'RedHat',
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

The last line in the image is an examlpe of what I need to get

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMdof.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   Text(
              r'$' + '333    '.trim(),
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Color(0xff210049),
                //fontSize: smallTextSize,
                fontFamily: 'RedHat',
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: I meant the spaces between 333 and ,00

Comment: okay. check my updated answer. is that one you are looking for ?

Comment: I can't believe that was so easy. I was looking for it since few hours. Thank u so much!!

Comment: please upvote and select the answer.